# Move multiple pdfs to multiple folders based on partial folder names

Tags: sorting, batch-file, pdf, directory

I have researched this site and many others on the net and I have not quite figured out what I need in order to complete this task.

What I have is a folder with 1000 PDF files.  Each PDF is a gym membership form with the name of a Gym Member and the start date in the file name.  I need to move these PDFs to a master folder that already contains subfolders.  These subfolders match the name of the gym members, but they do not contain dates.  They do however, contain a specific code enclosed in parenthesis.

Example:
My GymForms folder contains the 1000 PDFs. (Source Folder)
C:\Users\BlackPC\Desktop\GymForms

Alan Givens - H-9 1-16-2016.pdf

Jane Doe - H-9 7-10-2015.pdf

John Henry - H-9 1-16-2016.pdf

William Falls - H-9 7-10-2015.pdf

My Master Folder (Destination Folder) contains subfolders with all the names of Gym Members.
C:\Users\BlackPC\Desktop\ActiveMembers

Alan Givens (33U)

Jane Doe (05R)

John Henry (05S)

William Falls

So the batch file below is what I have (which was modified from another user's post)... and it will work if the member folder (destination folder) does not contain any parenthesis.  In other words, when the batch is executed, the PDFs for Alan Givens, Jane Doe, and John Henry will not move/sort into their respective folders.  But the PDF for the member "William Falls" will sort into the correct folder without any issues.

So I'm hoping someone can help me fix it and get it to do what I want?  In essence I need this batch file tweaked so the PDF can still sort when the destination folder contains parenthesis in the name.  Or, the batch file tweaked so it sorts the PDFs into the destination folders based on the first 9 characters of the folders name?

Thanks in advance!

-BATCH FILE-

```
@echo off

setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

pushd "C:\Users\HPC6250\Desktop\GymForms"

for /d %%I in (C:\Users\HPC6250\Desktop\ActiveMembers\*) do (

for %%F in (*) do (

    for /f %%A in ('echo %%~nF ^| find /i "%%~nI"') do (

        set /p a="Moving %%F to %%I... "<NUL

        move "%%F" "%%I" >NUL

        echo Done.

    )

  )

)

popd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%I IN (
  'dir /b /ad "%destdir%\*" '
 ) DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1delims=(" %%s IN ("%%~I") DO (
  IF EXIST "%sourcedir%\%%s*" ECHO(MOVE "%sourcedir%\%%s*" "%destdir%\%%I\"
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

The required MOVE commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files.  Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file moved`)

Read a directory list of the destination subdirectories into `%%I`

tokenise `%%I` using `(` as a delimiter, first portion (up to, but not including the delimiter) to `%%s`

If there are files in the source named `%%s*` move them to the destination+the full name of directory found

I wonder how you intend to deal with two "John Smith"s.

Comment: My hats off to you my friend.  Your .bat coding worked like a charm and did exactly what I needed it to do.  Thank you for your quick posting of the solution.  I truly appreciate it as you have saved me from a headache!